# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function but I cannot work out why not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am writing a little react app and I am trying to get data from a graphql server. I think (big emphisis on the word think) I am querying it correctly however it compiles but then gives me the following error message:

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

It refers to line 16 which is where I define the Users function.

After a bit of googling a came across this: [TypeError: Object(...) is not a function reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997481/typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-reactjs)
Whereby they seem to point to the person not importing/exporting there function correctly. However I do not believe I am doing that wrong. Any help or pointing in the right direction would be wonderful.

Thank you for reading and stay safe :)

code snippets:

Users file:

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-apollo";
import { gql } from "graphql-tag";

const QUERY_ALL_USERS = gql`
    query getUsers {
        users{
            name
            role
            createdAt
        }
    }
`;

export const Users = () => {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(QUERY_ALL_USERS);

    if (loading) return 'Loading...';
    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
    const users = data.users.map((u) => {
         return (
            <li>
                {u.name} <strong>{u.role}</strong>
            </li>
        )
    })
    return (
        <ul>
            { users }
        </ul>
    );
};
```

App.js:

```
import { Users } from "./Users";
.
.
.
class App extends Component {
  

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <header>
         .
         .
         .
        </header>
        <Users />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like an old/deprecated way to import GQL. Are you sure you meant to import from `react-apollo`/`graphql-tag` and not `@apollo/client`?

Comment: @PaulS. I tried this but it is still pointing towards the user function not being a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it like this

import gql from 'graphql-tag';

Basically remove {} wrap

Comment: unfortunately this did not resolve the issue. It still pointed towards the User function not being a function.

Comment: I think maybe you can also try to put mapping function directly into render part instead of calling only as {users} . Like this {data.users.map((u) => {
         return (
            <li>
                {u.name} <strong>{u.role}</strong>
            </li>
        )
    })}

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the mapping through the user into the return statement. Or at `if (data)` before the return. Seems like the users prop data on is being read before the response has been received.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-apollo";
import { gql } from "graphql-tag";

const QUERY_ALL_USERS = gql`
    query getUsers {
        users{
            name
            role
            createdAt
        }
    }
`;



export const Users = () => {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(QUERY_ALL_USERS);

    if (loading) return 'Loading...';
    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
    function User(){
       let users 
       if(data && data?.user){
        users = = data.users.map((u) => {
         return (
            <li>
                {u.name} <strong>{u.role}</strong>
            </li>
        )
        })
       }
        return users
     }
     
    return (
        <ul>        
            {!loading && <User/> }
        </ul>
    );
};
```

see full code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

It said Object is not a function, in react, you can't use an object as a component, it has to be a function. Instead of doing
`<ul>{ users }</ul>`, try to create a function User, return the map array through the function

```
Function User(){
  let user
  if(data && data?.users){
   users = data.users.map((u) => {
     return (
        <li>
            {u.name} <strong>{u.role}</strong>
        </li>
       )
  })}
   return user
}
```

then changed it to

```
<ul><User /></ul>
```

let me know if that works.

Comment: In the app.js file I can query the apollo server as such:

this.props.client.query({
      query:gql`
      query getUsers {
        users{
            name
            role
            createdAt
        }
    }
      `
    }).then(result => {console.log(result)})

This result shows that data.users in an array. I think it is something to do with how i am querying the server and nothing to do with if Users is a function or not.

even reducing the user function to simply the useQuery hook still yields the same error

Comment: It's likely your query come back as asynchronously, are you sure it's loaded initially?

Comment: Just as @sculs pointed out, usually api call returned asynchronously, so you need to do a validation check there to make sure data is indeed available, otherwise, it would likely be an empty object {}.

Comment: I just updated it, I think that is the issue. let me know if that works.